# export mysql data into pdf file

Tags: mysql, export

I want to export mysql table into pdf format. Please help me

I have tried this code. Here Is my code

**My.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jass12", $con);




$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ja");

 $i = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

@$csv_output .='"'.$row['Field'].'","';

$i++;}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ja");

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";

}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
@$filename = $file."_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time());

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: xls" . date("Y-m-d") . ".xls");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".xls");

print $csv_output;

exit;
?>
```

It produces error & also give as output as xls file.

I want to get the exact coding which convert the database file into pdf.

Please help me

Comment: See this link  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-buildpdfphp/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: all files you are creating in xls format then how this will generate pdf :)

Comment: will you provide me the exact code for pdf i really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

try using FPDF http://www.fpdf.org/.